# Circuit breaker design pattern sleep vs time.AfterFunc

Tags: design-patterns, go

I am trying to create a [Circuit breaker pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern), I want to execute a command [exec.Command](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd.Run) and if it fails, retry in X defined amount of time, for testing purposes, I am doing something like this for testing `time.AfterFunc`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func myFunc() error {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Printf("i = %+v\n", i)
        if i%3 == 0 {
            return fmt.Errorf("error")
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {

    run := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    run <- struct{}{}

    for {
        select {
        case <-run:
            err := myFunc()
            if err != nil {
                time.AfterFunc(3*time.Second, func() {
                    run <- struct{}{}
                })
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

`time.AfterFunc` works  for the above code, but not for the example below, I had to replace it with a `sleep` in order to achieve the expected results:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
    "time"
)

func Exec(done chan<- error) error {
    cmd := exec.Command("./start")
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    go func() {
        done <- cmd.Wait()
    }()
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var (
        run  = make(chan struct{}, 1)
        done = make(chan error, 1)
    )

    Exec(done)

    for {
        select {
        case <-run:
            err := Exec(done)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                // time.AfterFunc(3*time.Second, func() {
                time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
                run <- struct{}{}
            }
        default:
            select {
            case err := <-done:
                fmt.Println(err)
                run <- struct{}{}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The content of `./sleep`:

```
#!/bin/sh

sleep 3
```

And for testing, creating an error, I toggle perms:

```
chmod -x sleep
chmod +x sleep
```

Therefore wondering what are the differences between using `time.AfterFunc` and `time.Sleep` and what could be the best way of implementing this pattern.

Comment: In the top example, you are doing a busy wait if you get an error until the retry time is ready. The loop will execute as fast as it can until the AfterFunc runs.

Comment: What **expected results** is it not achieving?  Not waiting 3 seconds, panic'ing?

Comment: @sberry yes, basically I want to wait X amount of time before re-trying again.

Comment: What is it doing that is not expected?  I mean, describe what bahavior you observe.  Does it run more often than 3s?  Does it act differently (timing) as you change the executable bit?  Describe what happens.

Comment: @sberry after creating an error, panics ``fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`` but for been available to reproduce probably you could copy & paste the code and, runit and then just remove the ``sleep`` file or change permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you hit the default case, the select ends immediately. In the top example, after you execute `AfterFunc` the for loop runs continually until `run` has items (after 3 seconds). Busy waits are usually bad. With the `sleep` solution, you never have a busy wait, which is good. I'm not sure I fully follow what you are trying to accomplish with the nested selects in the second example though.

Why do you need channels and asynchrony at all? Why not just:

```
retryCount := 0
for retryCount < 3 {
   err := doSomethingScary()
   if err == nil{
     //success! return results!
   } else{
     //failure! wait and retry
     time.Sleep(time.Second) //time.sleep is a good non-busy wait
   }
}
// max tries exceeded. Return error.
```

Comment: Hi, I need the channels because I need to know when the command exited mainly because the ``cmd.Wait()``

Comment: The command is done when `cmd.Wait()` returns. If you want to do a timeout then a channel based approach may be appropriate, but right now you are just doing retries.